# How can i give this isomorphism between a Galois group and $S_3$?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I have shown that if $x$ is the nontrivial cubic root of the unity and that if $y$ is the real cubic root of $2$, then $Q(x,y)$ is a Galois extension whose Galois group has order $6$.

I know that the Galois group is determined by the automorfisms:

$α↦ωα,ω↦ω,α↦ωα,ω↦ω^{-1},α↦ω^2α,ω↦ω$,

$α↦ω^2α,ω↦ω ^{-1},α↦ω^3α,ω↦ω,α↦ω^3α,ω↦ω^{-1}$

The question is how can I make explicit the isomorphism between this Galois group and $S_3$?  drawing the Galois correspondence?

Comment: Hint: You just need to find two automorphisms that do not commute.

Comment: Yes, i have that. One is wich sends ω to ω^2  and the other is wich sends α to ωα, that shows that the group doesn`t conmute and then its isomorphic to S3, but how can i made explicit that isomorphism?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Take your pick of an automorphism of order $3$ and one of order $2$ and pick which $3$-cycle and $2$-cycle you would like them to correspond to.

Comment: If i send any automorphism of order 2 to any 2-cycle in S3 and any autom of order 3 to any 3-cycle is correct?

Comment: Yes, any of those choices will indeed work (this is a bit of a stroke of luck and will not usually be the case).

Comment: ok, thank´s a lot

Comment: The reason why this works in THIS case, and doesn't usually, is because $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$, something that is NOT the case for $n > 3$. Note that $D_3$ is generated by any non-trivial rotation and any reflection. The "standard" way to map the Galois group of $x^3 - 2$ to $S_3$ is to use the generators $\omega \mapsto \omega^2$ (which swaps the non-real roots) and $\sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{2}\omega$ (which permutes the roots in a 3-cycle).